# Why wordpress Houzez's theme's Search feature not working?

Tags: wordpress, search

I have installed the wordpress theme `Houzez` for my website. Then I have imported the demo contents into that. But the `Search` feature in the theme is not working. When I use the search button the attributes sending to the same page itself, so the same page keep reloading. [This](http://rayyaneyes.qa/) is my website address.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a page that you set as "Advanced Search Results" so it can show the search results.

What is happening is that when you click search, the theme does not know where to show the results, because the page of results does not exist, so he goes back to the homepage.